# format single quote in SQL statement

Tags: python

My question is simple, in Python, How do I format a SQL statement that contains single quotes in it?

I have a place name

```
"Musee d'Orsay"
```

What I want is

```
"Musee d\'Orsay"
```

so, I tried replace single quote by using following statement

```
str.replace("'","\'")
```

but, it return the original string. Can you give me any help?

double slash worked well.

```
str.replace("'","\\'")
```

---

OK, Thanks for all response. I have figured it out.

I must escape it by doubling the single quote.

> str.replace("'","''")
>
> INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (Musee d''Orsay);

It works for me.

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: In 'Musee d/'Orsay' did you mean 'Musee d\'Orsay'?

Comment: You really should use parameterized queries, instead of constructing the SQL query via string interpolation or concatenation.

Comment: You generally let the database connector deal with escaping values by using SQL parameters:  `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column1=? and column2=?', (param1, param2))`; this prevents SQL injection attacks as well. Consult your specific database library for details on the exact parameter syntax supported (it could be one or two of `?`, `%s`, `:1`, `:param_name` and `%(param_name)s`).

Comment: It didn't help me sir, python3?

Answer (score 9):

Your should not create sql queries by preparing the string that will go in it : you sould use placeholders and let the library doing the escaping work for you.

That exact syntax may change depending on the database you use. For example, in [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) :

```
m = "Musée d'Orsay"
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE museum=?', m)
```